# i want to read .bin file in my objective -c project and want to parse data accordingly

Tags: c++, iphone, objective-c, binary-data, foundation

i want read data from the binary file named "xyz.bin"    and want to parse data according to algorithm can any buddy suggest how to  get dat from binary file and perform read and write operation on that binary file

Comment: Have you looked at [`ifstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/)?

Comment: @Kerrek SB:actually i didn't work on file handling                               can u suggest me an example for read and write  .bin file ?

Comment: No idea what you mean by "file handling", but you just use the `read` method on ifstreams and the `write` method on ofstreams for reading and writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want

NSData's

`+ dataWithContentsOfURL:` or `+ dataWithContentsOfFile:` for input

and

`– writeToFile:options:error:` or  `– writeToURL:atomically:` for output

What you do with the data in between is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

if you're trying to access a file within your application bundle, you need to get the full path to it: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: FILENAME ofType: FILEEXTENSION]

This returns an NSString, which you can pull a UTF8String out of and pass to fopen.